# SwiftUI: store closure in environment?

Tags: swiftui

I would like child views of a given view to be able to call a common closure defined on the parent.

So the parent view would have a closure:

```
var testClosure:(()->())?
```

Is there a way to make that closure available throughout the view hierarchy without having to pass it down through each view down the chain?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it with `EnvironmentKey`/`EnvironmentValue` and pass it through using `.environment`:

```
typealias MyClosure = (() -> ())?

private struct ClosureKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue : MyClosure = { }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var myClosure : MyClosure {
        get { self[ClosureKey.self] }
        set { self[ClosureKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @Environment(\.myClosure) var closure
    
    var testClosure : MyClosure = {
        print("Here")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildView()
            .environment(\.myClosure, testClosure)
    }
}

struct ChildView : View {
    @Environment(\.myClosure) var closure
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world")
            .onAppear {
                closure?()
            }
    }
}
```