# SwiftUI: reference represented view controller?

Tags: swiftui

I have created a view I use when showing a UIViewController subclass.

```
struct CarView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var viewModel:CarViewModel
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CarVC {
        let vc = CarVC()
        vc.viewModel = viewModel
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController:CarVC, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

In the SwiftUI view I show it like so:

```
...
CarView(viewModel: carViewModel)
...
```

All works great.

When I want to call functions from the SwiftUI view containing CarView, how can I call functions declared on the actual `CarVC` instance wrapped in the CarView?

So if CarVC has a function called `showModel()`, how can the SwiftUI container call that function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling functions from UIViewController in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923718/calling-functions-from-uiviewcontroller-in-swiftui)

Comment: I'll check it out.

Comment: You've also never responded to my answer on one of your past questions resolved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748549/swiftui-store-closure-in-environment

Comment: It depends on where do you want to call the function from. Would you provide demo code for your use-case?